# How to add difference of dictionaries to one of the dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
limit = {'apple':'3','watermelon':'5','kiwi':'5','banana':'3','Strawberry':'18'}

fridge = {'apple': 10, 'kiwi': 10,'Strawberry': 20}
```

I have these 2 dictionaries and I want to compare them in python. I can find the difference between them with this code:

```
new = [d for d in sınır if d not in dolap]
print(new)
```

and my output is this:

```
['watermelon', 'banana']
```

but I want my output to be like this:

```
'banana':0 ,'watermelon':0
```

and I want to add these outputs to the `fridge` dict.

Basically I want to see my output like this:

```
fridge = {'apple': 10, 'kiwi': 10, 'Strawberry': 20, 'banana':0 ,'watermelon':0}
```

can you help me about it?

Comment: It's great to want something. But you have to do something to acheive it beyond relying on the kindness of strangers

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes sir, you are right about it. i am kinda new on this so i am not really experienced about stackerflow but i get your point and i edited my question

Comment: Your edit is literally "can you help me". All the substance was added by other users. I hope you learn a lot from this. I've removed my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all fruits from `limit` and have a look if they exist in `fridge`:

```
limit ={'apple':'3','watermelon':'5','kiwi':'5','banana':'3','Strawberry':'18'}
fridge= {'apple': 10,  'kiwi': 10,'Strawberry': 20}
diff = {k: 0 if k not in fridge else fridge[k] for (k, v) in limit.items()}
print(diff)
```

Output:

```
{'apple': 10, 'watermelon': 0, 'kiwi': 10, 'banana': 0, 'Strawberry': 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
new = {d: 0 for d in limit if d not in fridge}
```

would get you the `new` dict that you want.

and you can extend `fridge` with that by

```py
fridge.update(new)
```